# How.. get element by class, grab id, and use id as variable to pass to php

Tags: javascript

I'm running a function on an interval. I need to get element by class name, use the id of each and pass it into a function as a variable.

I've tried looping through each class name and passing the id to php but it passes an array (i think) or maybe an html index which i cant separate.

```
$(".eachUnread").each(function() {
    var newId = this.id;
    $(".eachUnread").load("../php/unreadEach.php?id="+newId);
    console.log(newId);
});
```

I also tried..

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("eachUnread");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var newId = x[i].id;
    console.log(newId);
    $(".eachUnread").load("../php/unreadEach.php?id="+newId);
    }
```

When the .eachUnread div loads its cycles through all the id's. How do I get it to load only the correct id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply this...

```
  $(".eachUnread").each(function() {
      $(this).load("../php/unreadEach.php?id="+this.id);
  });
```

Comment: This worked, can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need add param for each `function(index, item)` method and use attr for get id `var newId = $(item).attr('id');`

```
$(".eachUnread").each(function(index, item) {
    var newId = $(item).attr('id');
    $(".eachUnread").load("../php/unreadEach.php?id="+newId);
    console.log(newId);
});
```

```js
$(".eachUnread").each(function(index, item) {
    var newId = $(item).attr('id');
    $(".eachUnread").load("../php/unreadEach.php?id="+newId);
    console.log(newId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='eachUnread' id='test1'>A</div>
<div class='eachUnread' id='test2'>B</div>
<div class='eachUnread' id='test3'>C</div>
```